# Can the Amazon Kindle work with my Ubuntu hotspot?

Tags: wireless, networking, adhoc, kindle

I wanted to use my Ubuntu laptop here as a hotspot for my Kindle (v3.3)
But when I scan the wireless network on my Kindle and select to connect to the ubuntu wireless hotspot, then my kindle says its an unsupported Wi-Fi network:

```
Enterprise or peer-to-peer Wi-Fi networks are not supported...
```

What can I do to make it work, my laptop has a Intel PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] eth1

Wired connection:
 - Interface: Ethernet (eth0) 
 - Driver: 8139too

IPv4
 - IP address: 192.168.0.29 
 - Broadcast Adr: 192.168.0.255
 - Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
 - Default Route and Prim DNS: 192.168.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Most wireless hotspots created using a *wireless adapter* are not true "infrastructure" access points but are ["ad-hoc"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network) peer-to-peer networks.

Unfortunately, as the error indicates, the Kindle *does not* support ad-hoc or enterprise networks, only the "infrastructure" kind which is usually created with a wireless router or wireless access point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://exain.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/making-a-wifi-hotspot-access-point-using-linux-wifi-lan-cardusb-adapter/) document could help you? However, I'm not sure if it's worth the trouble...